# How to use `fastapi_another_jwt_auth` in the middleware instead of via dependency injection in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, fastapi

I have a FastAPI project which uses `fastapi_another_jwt_auth` as a way of authenticating users. I'd intend to implement it in most of my endpoints except for a few whitelisted ones, but I find it hard to unit test endpoints that require authentication so I'm thinking of implementing it in a middleware with a simple `if-else` check for whitelisted endpoints. This way, I just need to disable the middleware to run unit tests and testing for authentication becomes trivial since we're just testing against a whitelist.

The API for `fastapi_another_jwt_auth` seems designed around the concept of Dependency Injection for FastAPI. Is there a way to use the same library in the middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code for `fastapi_another_jwt_auth`. Apparently, when injecting, the framework runs the AuthJWT constructor, which takes in the `Request` and `Response` object. This is shown below.

```py
class AuthJWT(AuthConfig):
    def __init__(self,req: Request = None, res: Response = None):
        ...
```

Once it is successfully initialised, we can then use the `.jwt_required()` method.

So the way to implement it in the middleware is:

```py
@app.middleware("http")
async def middleware_callback(req, call_next):
    if not whitelisted: # this is pseudocode
        auth = AuthJWT(req)
        auth.jwt_required() # throws error when user is not authenticated

    # rest of the logic
    ...
```

This way, I can manage all authentication at the middleware level and I don't have to inject the `AuthJWT` object into my view functions.

Comment: It's worth noting that anything used in a Depends construct in FastAPI is a regular class or function behind the scenes, and can be used as such if you want to use them outside of an endpoint context. In this specific case you could also append a dependency to a root instance of `APIRouter` and have it be called for every request instead of making a middleware - in that case the regular dependency hierarchy would be resolved.